# The limit of this sequence $a_n=\frac{\ln(n^2+n+2)}{\ln(n^2+n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried this: $a_n=\frac{\ln(n^2+n+2)}{\ln(n^2+n+1)}=\frac{\ln(n^2+2n-n+2)}{\ln(n^2+n+1)}=\frac{\ln(n(n-1)(n+2))}{\ln(n^2+n+1)}$ and I did calculations, but I don't get a good result!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\frac{\ln(n^2+n+2)}{\ln(n^2+n+1)}=\frac{\ln n^2+\ln\left(1+\frac 1n+\frac2{n^2}\right)}{\ln n^2+\ln\left(1+\frac 1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

With *equivalence* of functions: a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, therefore
$$a_n\sim_\infty\frac{\ln(n^2)}{\ln(n^2)}=1\quad\text{for }n>1.$$